# What is the term for making an application that works within a website without a browser?

Tags: web

So basically, I want to make a program that works without a browser. For example, creating an auto login for a website within a program but it does not user a webbrowser. After auto logging in, I want the program to display in a textbox some of the data on the page? To sum it up, I want to know what this part of programming is called so I can research and learn about it. Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Do you want to run a desktop application as if it were a desktop app (i.e. no browser UI)?

Comment: Yes that's what I want to do. So basically, in this program I would login to a website WITHOUT a browser and it'll display in a textbox what shows on the site. I would have to login first however.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is that you want an **http client** built in to your program. That is what it is called. It won't be a "browser" but will interact with the web site you are trying to login to and show data from.

There are many libraries for different programming languages that you can use for an http client. Without knowing what language you are using, it is difficult to provide an exact recommendation.

One example is the [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org) library for the PHP language. It is an http client and can be used for the type of things you mentioned.

Another example is [Request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) which works with the Python language.

Comment: You're welcome! C# has a class that supports http client capabilities called "HttpClient" so you should have no trouble doing what you need. Have a great day!